# socket.io can connect in local, but cant connect in real live server

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, redis, socket.io

When I test in local, it works, but when I put it to real live server, after some testing with the code below, I found that client side will only connect to my local `socket.js` not server
`socket.js`

```
http.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 8080');
});
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var socket = io.connect('localhost:8080');
});
```

so I change index.blade.php connect to my `$ipaddress`, and `cosole.log` the status of connected: false still cant connect

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var socket = io.connect($ipaddress);
    console.log(socket);
});
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue. Check to make sure that port is open and accepting connections.

Comment: @FrankerZ, i have upload 2 picture of my iptables, both input and output are accept port 8080

Comment: If you just call `var socket = io();` it will attempt to connect using an auto-discovery. Have you tried that to see if it connects?